# How to improve in-text math expressions with multiple delimiters such asl `(`, `|`?

Tags: math-mode, equations, delimiters

Consider this equation:

```
first $\lceil (cN-n) |S_{n+1}|\rceil$ points
```

which renders to:

[image]

Is there a way to improve this, from the perspective of readability? The only improvement I could suggest is:

```
first $\lceil\, (cN-n) |S_{n+1}|\,\rceil$ points
```

which renders to:

[image]

I believe it would even better to read, if the interior of the ceiling would be shrinked only a bit, so the ceiling delimiters are a bit higher.

```
\documentclass{article}  
\begin{document}
first $\lceil\, (cN-n) |S_{n+1}|\,\rceil$ points
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** replaced minimal class with article, as suggested by egreg.

Comment: I suggest scaling up the `\_ceil`s and introducing a little space before the `\rceil` and in between `)` and `|`. I'd omit extra spacing before `(` because this glyph is already curved away from the `\lceil` a bit. `first $\bigl\lceil (cN-n)\, |S_{n+1}| \,\bigr\rceil$ points`. Consider reading chapter 18 of the TeXbook "Fine Points of Mathematics Typing".

Comment: @HenriMenke, thanks, why not make this as an answer?

Comment: Done. I added some more words and an image of the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest scaling up the `\_ceils` and introducing a little space before the `\rceil` and in between `)` and `|`. I'd omit extra spacing before `(` because this glyph is already curved away from the `\lceil` a bit.

```
\documentclass{article}  
\begin{document}
first $\bigl\lceil (cN-n)\, |S_{n+1}| \,\bigr\rceil$ points
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Consider reading chapter 18 of the TeXbook, "Fine Points of Mathematics Typing". It is very eyeopening regarding how to type mathematical formulas in TeX. Also the author Donald E. Knuth is not only the author of TeX, but also a professional mathematician.

Comment: +1, but I would use `\,` *xor* `\bigr`, that is, not both. Please, [avoid the `minimal` class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/), even if it's used in the question.

Comment: @egreg Why not `\,` and `\bigr`? Knuth also does this, e.g. in exercise 18.21. Sorry for the `minimal` class, I know not to use it, but copy-pasta was easier `;-)`

Comment: Exercise 18.21 is about a different situation: Knuth always uses a thin space after `\{` and before `\}` when the set is described with a condition, as opposed to listing its elements. So the presence of `\,` is independent from the fact that another delimiter is next to the closing brace. In the present case, I find the thin space not necessary if `\bigr\rceil` is used, but it's just my opinion.